# Retrieving minix OS version

Tags: kernel, minix

I'm having a project for the university in which (above others ) i have to get the minix os version from kernell call. This is what i have come to (with some help):

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    char M3ca1[23];
    message ml;
    m.m_u.m_m1.m3ca1= OS_VERSION;
    char temp=_syscall(MM,69,&m);
    printf("the os version is %c\n",temp);
    return 0;
}
```

And i get multiple errors.

Comment: What are the "multiple errors"?

Comment: I know very little about Minix, but seems like you're missing several definitions of variables.  I'd say start with "Hello, world", get that working, and then add on pieces one-by-one.

Answer (score 0):

This code does what you are asking for:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<minix/config.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv) {
    printf("the os version is %s.%s\n",OS_RELEASE,OS_VERSION);
    return 0;
}
```

If this is a university project I doubt this is what is being asked of you. Sure you aren't being asked to implement a new system call that gives the os version, and then write a small program that calls it?

******** Edit after many years due to a recent comment   ***

If you want to grab this from the running current instead of statically, you want to look at the uname(2) manpage. uname will fill a struct for you with all OS release, version, arch, and so forth.

Don't have a running minix machine to put together/verify a quick program to call and print this info. Should be straight forward. Might replace this paragraph with sample program.

Comment: NB this is the version at compile time, not at run time.

Comment: @Polluks Please look at dates on questions. After 8 years, both the question and answer provider have moved on, and/or often the question has been edited (as is this case, many times).